# click on listview, android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

I would like to click on an item of a listview to show another listview of other items, what can I do?
in my application I have a main Activity, where I have inserted a bottom view navigation, when you click on an item in the bottom view menu, the corresponding fragment appears in the main activity.
my listview is in the first fragment, and in the same fragment the next screen must appear, after the click in the listview.
do I have to replace the fragment of the listview with another one or can I replace only the listview? how?
Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of those options (replacing the fragment / list view), you could use the onItemSelected method to repopulate the list view object with the new list. Since you already know how to do this, it would seem the simplest option. A simple switch statement would suffice.